# Visual studio code :Studio Could not find an installed version of Gradle

Tags: cordova

I am running my app using this command:

`ionic cordova run android -l`

it gives error like:

> Android Studio project detected
> ANDROID_HOME=/media/USerName/data/sdk/
> JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
>
> studio Could not find an installed version of Gradle either in Android Studio or on your system to install the gradle wrapper. Please includegradle in your path, or install Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

Install Gradle from https://gradle.org/install - that should solve your problem.

Comment: First of all thanks; i have install latest gradle ans resolve it.